# Does switching routers when using same IP cause temp downtime?

Tags: networking, routing, ip, router, mac

Still learning networking but from my understanding MAC Addresses are what route network traffic so if I switch out a router but configure them with the same IP does it take time for the new MAC address to be broadcasted for all network traffic to switch over to the new router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC addresses reside and operate at Layer 2 of the OSI networking model.

Routing occurs at Layer 3 of the OSI networking model.

In the strictest sense, routing isn't performed by way of the MAC address, because routing occurs at Layer 3 while MAC addresses operate at Layer 2.

That being said, and using a very simple example, when a local host needs to communicate with a remote host it must send that traffic to it's Default Gateway (router). In order to do that the host must resolve the IP address (Layer 3) of the router to it's MAC address (Layer 2). Once it's done that it sends the data in the form of Ethernet frames (on an Ethernet network) to the MAC address of the Default Gateway (router). The Default Gateway (router) then consults it's routing table to determine where to route/forward the traffic.

To more directly answer your question, because your internal hosts need to resolve the ip address of the router to it's MAC address, then swapping out the router will necessitate that the internal hosts resolve the ip address of the router to the MAC address of the new router. The MAC address of the old router will be cached by the OS on each host and each host will be unable to resolve the MAC address of the new router until the old MAC address expires in their MAC address cache (their ARP cache/table). You can manually flush the ARP cache/table on each host but it shouldn't be necessary with enough pre-planning on your end. The ARP cache/table is transient and in most cases the ARP cache/table entries will expire within about 5 minutes.